# Determining coefficients of the power series

Tags: real-analysis

(1) Determine the coefficients $\sum^{\infty}_{0} a_n z^n$ of the power series whose sum is $(1 − z)^{−2}$

(2) Determine the coefficients $\sum^{\infty}_{0} a_n z^n$ of the power series whose sum is $(1 − z)^{−2}$ for $|z| < 1$ by squaring $(1 − z)^{−1}$

Two problems out of my book have me stumped. I think I start by showing the series has a positive radius of convergence but then I'm not really sure how to proceed after this step. Help!

Comment: Please check my assumption that they were supposed to be $(1 - z)^{-2}$ and not $(1 - z) - 2$ as written.

Comment: What tools do you have at hand? (1) is trivial by the (extended) binomial theorem, (2) is an application of Cauchy product and simplifying the resulting sums if given the series for $(1 - z)^{-1}$.

Comment: Correct. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

HINTS (assuming that vonbrand’s interpretation is correct):

1. What is the power series for $f(z)=\frac1{1-z}$? It’s a **very** familiar series. What is the derivative with respect to $z$ of $\frac1{1-z}$?
2. The coefficient of $z^n$ in $$\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nz^n\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nz^n\right)$$ is $$\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}\;.$$ (This is the [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).)